# Tuning parameters of the classifier used by BaggingClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Say that I want to train `BaggingClassifier` that uses `DecisionTreeClassifier`:

```
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 1)
bc = BaggingClassifier(dt, n_estimators = 500, max_samples = 0.5, max_features = 0.5)
bc = bc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I would like to use `GridSearchCV` to find the best parameters for both `BaggingClassifier` and `DecisionTreeClassifier` (e.g. `max_depth` from `DecisionTreeClassifier` and `max_samples` from `BaggingClassifier`), what is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
param_grid = {
    'base_estimator__max_depth' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'max_samples' : [0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5]
}

clf = GridSearchCV(BaggingClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(),
                                     n_estimators = 100, max_features = 0.5),
                   param_grid, scoring = choosen_scoring)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

i.e. saying that `max_depth` "belongs to" `__` the `base_estimator`, i.e. my `DecisionTreeClassifier` in this case. This works and returns the correct results.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but I found one test in sklearn that does it the same way: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/tests/test_bagging.py

Comment: This is documented [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#composite-estimators-and-parameter-spaces).

Answer (score 10):

If you are using a pipeline then you can extend the accepted answer with something like this (note the double, double underscores):

```
model = {'model': BaggingClassifier,
         'kwargs': {'base_estimator': DecisionTreeClassifier()}
         'parameters': {
             'name__base_estimator__max_leaf_nodes': [10,20,30]
         }}
pipeline = Pipeline([('name', model['model'](**model['kwargs'])])
cv_model = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=model['parameters'], cv=cv, scoring=scorer)
```